# How to let user interact with the object when edit button is pressed in unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I do need some help to implement a way for the user to interact with the model like for example when the edit button is pressed I want the user to select on a part on the object that can highlight in yellow on unity with c#. Is there way or any logic? Let me know if you dont understand what I want to implement. thanks for your help.

Here is some code:

```
    public class BlowupController : MonoBehaviour {



    public void Editcomponents()
    {
        // let user interact when edit button (script) is called. 
          ClearText();
        RemoveStatus = !RemoveStatus;
        var imgs = reticle.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>(true);
        if (RemoveStatus)
        {
            foreach (var img in imgs)
            {
                img.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(255, 0, 0, 255);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var img in imgs)
            {
                img.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255);
            }
        }



    }




    public void ResetComponents(GameObject Remove)
    {
        Debug.Log("HI"); ;
        Debug.Log(value);
        ClearText();
        foreach (Animator ani in AnimotorList)
        {
            ani.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            ani.SetBool("Start", value);
        }
        if (RemoveStatus)
        {
            var imgs = reticle.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>(true);
            foreach (var img in imgs)
            {
                img.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255);
            }
            var on = Remove.transform.Find("Remove_On");
            on.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            var off = Remove.transform.Find("Remove_Off");
            off.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            RemoveStatus = !RemoveStatus;
        }        
        ResetPanel.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void UndoRemovingComponent(GameObject Remove)
    {
        if (UndoList.Count > 0)
        {
            ClearText();
            var ob = UndoList[UndoList.Count - 1];
            ob.SetActive(true);
            UndoList.Remove(ob);
            if (UndoList.Count == 0)
            {
                var imgs = reticle.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>(true);
                foreach (var img in imgs)
                {
                    img.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255);
                }
                var on = Remove.transform.Find("Remove_On");
                on.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                var off = Remove.transform.Find("Remove_Off");
                off.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                ResetPanel.SetActive(false);
                UndoPanel.SetActive(false);
                RemoveStatus = !RemoveStatus;
            }            

        }
    }



     private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(initialTimeDelay);
        if (reticle == null)
        {
            reticle = FindObjectOfType<Reticle>().gameObject;
        }
        TransformSync();        


    }


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question, but if you are trying to know if/when a user presses a key, you can use Input.GetKeyDown(). Example

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            print("space key was pressed");
        }
```

OR

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            print("space key was pressed");
        }
    }
```

Here, you replace space with the key you wish to check. Full documentation can be found on Unity docs https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

Comment: So, let me elaborate for you.. In Unity, I have a object where I want the user to interact with like select a specific part of the object and highlight. So,  I added a button (edit button), on my scene and Need help to implement a way for the user to interact and select a particular object and when the user selects a part I want to highlight and show a yellow color on that particular object. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you were doing this in scene view, i'd have said you should use Editor scripting. But since you require the feature in play mode and in the final version of your app/game, i think it would be easier to create your main object out of separate GameObjects, then bring them together to form the shape of the object you want. That way, you can easily check which part was selected by checking what GameObject was selected.

Comment: It is set up like that already.  But, need some implementation logic for the user to identify the object by selecting on it and then click on done the changes are there. is there a way?

Comment: Yes you can. What kind of changes do you want to make? Color? Size? Position?

Comment: So, first I want to make an action in my `Editcomponents()` method where I want to let the user select object and the selections turns yellow or any color.  As you can see right now in my `Editcomponents` method I am just removing objects.

Comment: Okay. In order to edit color, first you need to get the material on the selected object, then apply your new color

Comment: do you have any resource I can follow? Or show me a some implementation?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since your object is divided into separate parts, create a script called "CheckIfSelected" or something similar, then in the update method, use raycast  to check if the object is clicked. Once the object is clicked, get the material on the object, then change the color as such: (Sorry about the formatting and any possible typos, i am not using an ide)

```
function Update () {
         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
             var hit: RaycastHit;
             var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

             if (Physics.Raycast(ray, hit)) {
                 if (hit.transform.gameObject == gameObject ){
                      gameObject.renderer.material.color = new Color(1,1,1);
                 }
             }
         }
```

Comment: Yeah there were some issues with the code above. The `RaycastHit` thrown a error with `“Interface name is not valid at this point”` Along with the line `gameObject.renderer.material.color = new Color(1,1,1);`

Comment: I think `renderer` is deprecated.